# How to retrieve individual video revenue and views using YouTube API

Tags: php, laravel, youtube

I'm looking for guidance on using the YouTube API to fetch specific details for each video on my channel. While I can currently see the overall lifetime revenue and views for the entire channel, I want to retrieve individual statistics for each video. I want to know the earnings and views for every single video separately, as each video may generate different income and attract varying numbers of views.

I've explored the YouTube API, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract this granular information for each video. I am seeking code snippets or step-by-step instructions on how to achieve this using the YouTube API.

```
public function yte()
    {
        $params = [
            "ids" => "channel==MINE",
            "startDate" => "2023-10-01",
            "endDate" => "2023-12-31",
            "metrics" => "views,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,subscribersGained",
            "dimensions" => "day",
            "sort" => "day"
        ];


        $http_parameters = http_build_query($params);

        $url = "https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?{$http_parameters}";

        $access_token = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token
        ];

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($server_output === false) {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return  $response_object = json_decode($server_output);

        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            echo 'JSON decoding error: ' . json_last_error_msg();
        } else {
            var_dump($response_object);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What `dimensions` are available to you? It seems that there might be a value here that would split by video as well as day.